# How I pass custom Query in my Repository method in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

If I have a created a query with multiple filters, than how I pass in my repository method.

```
@Query(value=":customQuery",nativeQuery=true)
public List<Employee> findAllBYFilters(String customQuery,@Param("isActive") boolean isVisible, @Param("pageRequest") Pageable pageRequest);
```

Please guide me how I pass a complex query(which I create in service class by using multiple filters) in this method.

Comment: Please add the query to your question

Comment: Your syntax looks off to me.  The query itself should appear inside the `@Query` annotation, and the `:placeholders` should appear inside that raw query string.

Comment: @devReddit my query is created at run time on the basic of multiple conditions. 
I have write one method to create query at run time

Comment: I see what you try to do. I also think you'd probably want to use an EntityManager directly instead. Anyway, if you want to use the parameter `customQuery` in the value of `@Query`, you also need to specify it in the argument. In other words, add `@Param("customQuery")` before `String customQuery`

Comment: @jetto yes I used  EntityManager to solve this chalange